# How can I optimize these nested loops?

Tags: python, optimization, performance

Can anyone optimize this code block? It is working but running very slow.

```
maxsat = 0
possiblevotes = []
for i in range(1,int(numcats)+1):
    for j in range(1,int(numdogs)+1):
        possiblevotes.append('C' + str(i) + ' ' + 'D' + str(j))
        possiblevotes.append('D' + str(j) + ' ' + 'C' + str(i))
for m in possiblevotes:
    count = 0
    for n in votes:
        if m == n:
            count += 1
        elif m.split()[0] == n.split()[0]:
            count += 1
    if count > maxsat:
        maxsat = count
```

Comment: I'm concerned that your `numcats` variable is a non-integer data type. Are you cutting whole animals into fractions of animals? :-)

Comment: Have you tried running it through cProfile to see the slow parts?

Comment: Python version 2.7. Numcats is being read in from a string but cast as an int

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you are trying to do, particularly the votes/possiblevotes bit.

Comment: Use `itertools.product()` to generate `possiblevotes` *on the fly*. Don't store it in a (potentially *huge*) list.

Comment: 1) It's always better to profile your code to find slow parts than to ask blindly. 2) You haven't told us how large `numcats` and `numdogs` are. 3) There is clearly more code that you haven't posted. How do you know that the slow part is in the code you've posted? This isn't a bad question, per se, but it needs some more information (mostly profiling info).

Comment: You are comparing all votes with all *possible* votes? There is no need to generate all possible votes then. Just test if `n[0]` is either `C` or `D` and check the numbers.

Comment: What are you doing with `count`? Is that *only* used to find the `maxsat` value?

Comment: 1 ≤ cats ≤ 100, 1 ≤ dogs ≤ 100  and  0 ≤ votes ≤ 500

Comment: I'm trying to find the optimal maxsat and found only by checking them all that it is accurate but if there is some sort of shortcut I'd be interested in hearing about it

Comment: so you are creating 100*100*2 = 20000 possible votes, times 500 votes is 10.000.000 iterations in the loop.

Comment: @Martijn yeah that makes sense how can I cut this down?

Comment: i am not familiar with Python, but looks like you are creating new range inside your nested loop, at least try to take that out into a constant, that way it does not reallocate on every iteration

Answer (score 1):

There is *no need* to generate all possible votes. You can test your actual votes without having to generate the `possiblevotes` list, because you can easily calculate if an existing vote is possible or not.

You also only really count the 'stay' votes. It doesn't matter that you look for matching 'stay go' votes, because any 'stay go' vote for which `m == n` is true, `m.split()[0] == n.split()[0]` is *also* true. So you may as well drop that first count, and only look at the second.

Now you are just finding the maximum count for the `stay` votes. Using a `collections.Counter()` makes counting things easier:

```
import collections

vote_counts = collections.Counter(v.split()[0] for v in votes)

maxsat = vote_counts.most_common(1)[0][1]  # retrieve the most popular count
```

This calculates the same number your code calculated, but now we only have to loop over the votes *just once*, and only count 'stay' votes.

Contrast this with your loop, where you first loop `numcats * numdogs` times, then loop `numcats * numdogs * 2 * len(votes)` times. That a factor of `3 * numcats * numdogs` *larger*.

If you have to validate votes first, you can use:

```
from itertools import ifilter

numcats = int(numcats)
numdogs = int(numdogs)

def validvote(vote):
    stay, go = vote.split()
    cat, dog = sorted((stay, go))
    if (cat[0], dog[0]) != ('C', 'D'):
        return False
    if not (1 >= int(cat[1:]) >= numcats):
        return False
    if not (1 >= int(dog[1:]) >= numdogs):
        return False
    return True

vote_counts = collections.Counter(v.split()[0] for v in ifilter(validvote, votes))
```

You could also start using the *go* votes:

```
stay_votes = collections.Counter()
go_votes = collections.Counter()

for vote in ifilter(validvote, votes):
    stay, go = vote.split()
    stay_votes[stay] += 1
    go_votes[go] += 1
```

Now you can simply *subtract* the go votes from the stay vote tally (any tally falling to 0 is removed):

```
total_votes = stay_votes - go_votes

# Display top 10
for creature, tally in total_votes.most_common(10):
    print('{}: {:>#5d}'.format(creature, tally))
```

Of course, you *could also* do the calculation in one go:

```
total_votes = collections.Counter()

for vote in ifilter(validvote, votes):
    stay, go = vote.split()
    total_votes[stay] += 1
    total_votes[go] -= 1
```

but keeping the vote tallies separate might be interesting for later analysis.

Comment: well the problem is that I need to find THE best vote and the max amount of satisfied voters.. that's what maxsat is

Comment: @JoelSmith: Your code doesn't define what THE best vote *is*.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to determine also

Comment: @JoelSmith: The above code does the same thing your code did, but only needs to loop over 500 votes, then over < 500 vote tallies. That at least is faster.

Comment: it's a bit different.. votes are actually like this ['C1 D3', 'D2 C5'] first element is the vote for the animal to stay and second is animal to leave. Each vote is exactly one cat and one dog

Comment: @JoelSmith: your sample code does not reflect this. If your `votes` sequence contains nested lists, then your code doesn't count anything at all.

Comment: just strings of two votes (for and against) separated by a space

Comment: @JoelSmith: ah, right, you confused me for a moment there. But that is what my code handles; two votes that are separated on a line. It tests that the vote is indeed valid (C votes for D, or D votes for C) and that the numbers are within the valid range. Those tests are optional, and are only needed if there are any invalid votes in your data.

Comment: there is no identifier of who voted. it's just two separate anonymous votes in the string. keepvote(i.e. C1) space removevote(i.e. D4)

Comment: @JoelSmith: yes, I understood that.

Comment: @JoelSmith: After further analysis of your code, I reduced my solution to 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary instead of a list:

```
possiblevotes = {}
for i in range(1,int(numcats)+1):
    for j in range(1,int(numdogs)+1):
        possiblevotes['C' + str(i) + ' ' + 'D' + str(j)] = 0
        possiblevotes['D' + str(j) + ' ' + 'C' + str(i)] = 0
for n in votes:
    possiblevotes[n] += 1
....
```

Comment: There is absolutely *no need* to create all possible keys. Why not use `possiblevotes[n] = possiblevotes.get(n) + 1` for example? Or use `possiblevotes = collections.defaultdict(int)`, or use `collections.Counter()` and you can drop your (expensive) loop altogether.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if you use `possiblevotes.get(n,0) + 1` you could avoid TypeError since if there are no such item in the dict, get method will return None.

Comment: @scriptmonster: that was a typo on my part, yes, you need to add the `0` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The code takes a long time because of the nested loops. If you have 1000 cats, 1000 dogs, and 1000 votes, then the first set of loops runs 1000x1000 times; the second set runs 1000x1000x1000 times. If we can remove nested loops, then your code will run faster.

I noticed you seems to tally the votes, in which 'C1 D3' is the same as 'D3 C1'. I suggest you use the Counter class in the collections module to do the heavy lifting. Here is my solution:

```
import collections

if __name__ == '__main__':
    votes = ['C1 D3', 'D1 C5', 'D3 C1', 'd1 c1', 'c1 d3'] # Example votes

    # Normalize the votes: 'D3 C1' becomes 'C1 D3',
    # 'c1 d3' becomes 'C1 D3'
    normalized_votes = [''.join(sorted(v.upper().split())) for v in votes]

    # Count the votes
    counter = collections.Counter(normalized_votes)

    # Top 10
    print '--- TOP 10 ---'
    for vote, count in counter.most_common(10):
        print count, vote

    # Or print all
    print '--- ALL ---'
    for vote, count in counter.iteritems():
        print count, vote
```

#### Discussion

- This solution uses 4 loops: the first is to derive *normalized_votes*, the second is to create the *counter* variable. The last two loops deal with printing out the result. None of these loops are nested. One might argue that the implementation of the `Counter` class might contain nested loops, but I trust that this class is implemented as efficient as possible.
- One important step is to normalize the votes, which should greatly simplify your tally. While I have done it in one line, you can break it up into several steps to aid understanding.

  1. The first step is to convert all the votes to upper case: 'd3 c1' becomes 'D3 C1'.
  2. Next, I break them up into a list with the `split()` function: 'D3 C1' becomes ['D3', 'C1'].
  3. The third step is to sort each item: ['D3', 'C1'] becomes ['C1', 'D3']
  4. The final step glue them back together: ['C1', 'D3'] becomes 'C1 D3'

Comment: 'C1 D3' and 'D3 C1' are not the same. the first part of the string is which animal to keep and the second is which to get rid of

Comment: I did not know that. I did not see any evidence in your code. Any way, I am sure that you can still use the `Counter` class to simplify your solution. Also try to eliminate nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

vote_pattern = re.compile('^(C|D)\d+\s')

votes = ['123', 'A1123', 'cC32', 'C', 'D0', 'C11']
maxsat = sum(0 if vote_pattern.match(vote) is None else 1 for vote in votes)
```

You can change this awful sum to something like filter, of course.

Comment: Note that 'D0 ' is a correct vote here as well as 'C123 texttext'. To fix that just edit rhis regexp a little. Your algo accepts something like 'C123 texttext' as well, so I don't know exactly, what did you want.